# How to create a CGAL Nef_polyhedron_3 from a vertex/index buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, cgal, vertex

I want to do convex decomposition on a triangulated mesh. Looking at the CGAL documentation, convex decomposition operates on a `CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3` type, which can be constructed from a `CGAL::Polyhedron_3` type. But my input mesh is represented as a vertex buffer + index buffer, as follows:

```
struct Mesh {
    std::vector<Vector3> vertices;
    std::vector<int32_t> triangles;
};
```

How do I convert this to a CGAL polyhedron? I know I could write an OFF file and load that into the CGAL polyhedron object, but I don't want to introduce disk IO overhead if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is under the form of a polygon soup, as we call it in CGAL. There are functions to check if they are really a polygon mesh, and if so there are functions to construct a polygon mesh from it, including a Polygon_3. Look [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga8b9d12d817b5cc76f5a42d74eac75bf3) and [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#gac8fe80db9800265922ce469c36d97baa).